# is there any way to check if a connection id is alive?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I'm building a system with multiple SignalR instances, each of which is connected to a message bus.

Given a connection id, is there any way to check if the connection id is alive? If not, what would be the best practice to do this on the server side?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

When OnDisconnected fires on your hub the connection id in question is no longer alive.